# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8, udp

I am trying to covert a data recieved from a UDP connection. This original data looks like this,

> ♦   Drone ♥   1}(┐û¼t=☻ ô┐#─G┐╨]{=♀█}┐4h)┐0Gu={;f┐Drone 2 ♥   α∙Æûo♥╜α↑♦>r╕╧> .a╝╥▐←>ûÑσ>û┼è╗all
>     1}(┐û¼t=☻ ô┐#─G┐╨]{=♀█}┐4h)┐0Gu={;f┐α∙Æûo♥╜α↑♦>r╕╧> .a╝╥▐←>ûÑσ>û┼è╗    ♥   ☺   w83┐ö∟w╣ü┐ìù─;è6r?Uk►╗ï╣Ñ>♥   1}(┐û¼t
>   =☻ ô┐#─G┐╨]{=♀█}┐4h)┐0Gu={;f┐☺   ☻   ♥   ª¢─<ª¢─<ª¢─<½>↨9☺ ☻   GÜ♣╜ï◄-?êàî?i☻9=ò
>   0,?├÷p╛Q;3?♥   α∙Æ☼6è╝l╜E=$7.?☼♦ ={ :?♥   ƒçç=‼ù╥>ûo♥╜α↑♦>r╕╧> .a╝╥▐←>ûÑσ>û┼è╗☺   ☻
>   ♥   ª¢─<ª¢─<ª¢─ûo♥╜ª¢─<☻ ☻   α↑♦>r╕╧> .a╝ª¢─<☻ ♥   ╥▐←>ûÑσ>û┼è╗ª¢─<☻ ╝╗▐A
>       wwwww╫;@

When I tried to decode ,

```
unpacked_data = stringdata = data.decode('utf-8')
```

It gave an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "read_udp_multicast.py", line 27, in <module>
unpacked_data = stringdata = data.decode('utf-8')
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 4: invalid continuation byte.
```

I have tried decoding with others like 'latin-9' as well. It doesn't work. The data comes in as UDP packet. So not sure how to convert it to human readable format.

Comment: Ask the sender what encoding is that?

Comment: Also what makes you think that it is text, not some binary data?

Comment: Find out what encoding it is using chardet

Comment: I don't have an idea on what encoding type it comes with, as these data are sent from a third party tool. Is there any other way to check. i am kinda new to the socket programming. thanks!

Comment: That error message turns up thousands of results when used in a websearch. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: What is the _third party tool_?